# How to merge 2 rows and 2 columns to become 1 big box in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

How to merge 2 rows and 2 columns to become 1 big box in Bootstrap 4?

Before:

[image]

To be like this:

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">.col-3</div>
    <div class="col-3">.col-3</div>
    <div class="col-3">.col-3</div>
    <div class="col-3">.col-3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">.col-3</div>
    <div class="col-3">.col-3</div>
    <div class="col-3">.col-3</div>
    <div class="col-3">.col-3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can try grid layout https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid_item.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some changes to your html structure, also used some b-4 classes (`h-100`) to align it. read [boostrap-4 document](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) to understand grid system.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col border">.col-3</div>
        <div class="col border">.col-3</div>
        <div class="w-100"></div>
        <div class="col border">.col-3</div>
        <div class="col border">.col-3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="row h-100">
        <div class="col border h-100">.col-3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @mastersuse it's not my fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. Note i did not add background colors or classes to keep the answer clean

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">A</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">B</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">C</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">D</div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    F
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/bo4davh8/)